# how to use undomanager for sourceviewer

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I need to add undo redo feature to my source viewer. Below is my code.

```java
public class MyViewer extends SourceViewer {
    public MyViewer(final Composite parent, final int styles) {
        super(parent, null, styles);

        final Font font = JFaceResources.getFont(MyConstants.EDITOR_TEXT_FONT);
        getTextWidget().setFont(font);
        IUndoManager undoManager = getUndoManager(); //new TextViewerUndoManager(25);
        //setUndoManager(undoManager); //new TextViewerUndoManager(10));
        //undoManager.connect(this);
        if (undoManager != null) {
            undoManager.reset();
        } else {
            undoManager = new TextViewerUndoManager(25);
            setUndoManager(undoManager);
            undoManager.connect(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setDocument(final IDocument document) {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public void setHyperlinkPresenter(final IHyperlinkPresenter hyperlinkPresenter) throws IllegalStateException {
    ...
    }

}
```

I have added a key binding as seen in the below image.

[image]

Still the undo redo does not work. 
I am not sure if the key binding is wrong or i am missing something in my code or both. Please highlight my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below code from [here](http://gamjaradio.blogspot.in/)

```
viewer.getTextWidget().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
 @Override
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

 @Override
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
   if( isUndoKeyPress( e )){
     viewer.doOperation(ITextOperationTarget.UNDO);
   }  else if( isRedoKeyPress( e )) {
      viewer.doOperation(ITextOperationTarget.REDO);
   }
 }

  private boolean isRedoKeyPress(KeyEvent e) {
     return (( e.stateMask & SWT.CONTROL ) > 0) && ((e.keyCode =='y' ) (e.keyCode == 'Y'));
   }

   private boolean isUndoKeyPress(KeyEvent e) {
          return (( e.stateMask & SWT.CONTROL) > 0 ) && ((e.keyCode == 'z' ) (e.keyCode =='Z'));
   }
});
```

I was able to get undo and redo working after adding this code. Looks like the additional key binding i had done in the preference page was not needed. Now the preference page looks like this

[image]